# Wordpress - Grant specific plugin access to user

Tags: wordpress, plugins, permissions

I am using Yoast SEO plugin on my wordpress website.  I would want to allow my writer to access this plugin menu.

I have install Member Plugin to define the roles for my writer and enable the manage_options for my writer.  However, this options allowed all plugin access.  I do not want my writer to able to access my other plugin except the SEO plugin.

Could anyone advise what can I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score -3):

please use this plugin :

https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/

thanks